# Pros/Cons of hosting website on apache vm

Tags: reactjs, django, apache, virtual-machine, hosting

I recently have begun hosting my own website on an Apache Linux VM, through the Google Cloud compute engine. This project primarily used Django for backend & API call handling, while using React as the primary frontend engine.

Initially hosting the site was difficult for, but once it was running, it was fast, easy to tie to a domain, and performed all functionality as required.

My main question was, in this sort of web-application scenario, what would be some alternatives for hosting a site like this? Is hosting this kind of site on a VM appropriate? Are VMs expensive when compared to alternatives? How well would this scale with the number of users?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question which makes it off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you work with VM´s, scalability is based on CPU + Memory resources.
But if you try having some fun with Kubernetes, you will be able to handle scalability easily.

Here you can find some resources around Django for Containers;
[https://medium.com/@marvels0098/how-to-include-reactjs-app-in-docker-container-2e73068ce2d5][1]

In terms of "Hosting", have you tried solutions like DigitalOcean?
https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/
It will let you deploy a pre-built Django environment, and the community is always willing to help there.

Now, my kind advice will be to move to containers, the learning curve is a little bit complicated at the beginning, but at the end of the road, your life will be lot easier. Could you please share more details with us, as an example "concurrent users", "user peaks", more data on how many people is accessing that site, so we can all here at Stack Overflow give you better answers.

Thank you!